# Send variables to TinyMCE 4.0 while re-Initialize when browser window is resized

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, window-resize

I wonder if there is a way to send a string to toolbar(s) settings of TinyMCE 4.0 and re-Init when re-sizing the browser window.

Here I'm using "enquire" as a script to handle the changes but I don't mind any technique. I tried the ed.on('init') and PreInit with no hope.

**Only need to send the updated variables of bar1 and bar2 and reset the editor**

```
<script>


    var bar1 ='';
    var bar2 = '';


    _simpleInt = {
        mode: 'exact',
        elements: "TEXT_ID",
        selector: "textarea:not(.advanced-editor)",
        editor_selector: "simple-editor",
        theme: "modern",
        editor_deselector: /(mceNoEditor|NoRichText)/,
        width: '100%',
        height: '200',
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        setup: function (ed) {
            ed.on('init', function (args) {

            });
        },

        plugins: [
             "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker template",
             "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
             "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor dotNetImage qrcode youtube autosave"
        ],
        toolbar1: bar1,
        toolbar2: bar2,
        image_advtab: true
    }
    enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 1024px)", {
        setup: function () {

        },
        match: function () {
            bar1 = 'bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | ';
            bar2 = 'undo redo | cut copy paste | table | emoticonsqrcode  image | link unlink anchor qrcode |   ';
            tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, "TEXT_ID");
            tinymce.init(_simpleInt);
            //alert("a")
        },
        unmatch: function () {
            bar1 = 'bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | | ltr rtl |  outdent indent | | forecolor backcolor | searchreplace | ';
            bar2 = 'undo redo | cut copy paste | table | emoticonsqrcode  image | link unlink anchor qrcode |  hr nonbreaking inserttime | visualchars visualblocks | removeformat restoredraft | ';
            tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, "TEXT_ID");
            tinymce.init(_simpleInt);


        }
    });

 tinymce.init(_simpleInt);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way .. I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/hsobhy/pen/bpWOMr) with the solution. I also used a function to delay the init to after resize stops.

```
  var myBar1;
  var myBar2;

  function iniTinyMce() {
      if($(window).width() > 1100) {
          myBar1 = "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image";
          myBar2 = "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons";
          setTimeout(function() {
              tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, "example");
              tinymce.init(_settings);
          }, 100);
      }
      else {
          myBar1 = "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter ";
          myBar2 = "print preview media | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image";
          setTimeout(function() {
              tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, "example");
              tinymce.init(_settings);
          }, 100);
      }
      var _settings = {
          selector: 'textarea',
          height: 500,
          theme: 'modern',
          plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak', 'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen', 'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality', 'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'],
          toolbar1: myBar1,
          toolbar2: myBar2,
          image_advtab: true,
          templates: [{
              title: 'Test template 1',
              content: 'Test 1'
          }, {
              title: 'Test template 2',
              content: 'Test 2'
          }]
      }
  }
   // Init tinyMce on load
  iniTinyMce();

   // After Resize end
  $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
      // Init tinyMce
      iniTinyMce();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
      if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
      this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
          $(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
      }, 500);
  });
```